# Citing a linux manual page in bibtex?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I'd like to cite the man page for the `iostat` command. 
I found the @manual entry. Is this the accepted way of citing Linux man pages?

I've populated the fields below based on what the man page says on my system.

```
@manual{iostat,
 title      = "iostat(1) Linux User's Manual",
 %author        = "",
 %organization  = "",
 %address   = "",
 %edition   = "",
 year       = "2013",
 month      = "July",
 %note      = "",
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome, manual seems to be ok, misc would be ok as well, i think. If you have to cite multiple man pages, consiider switching to `biblatex` and creat a new entry type.

Comment: Man pages do have authors. If this is the same document as https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/iostat.1.html, then in my view it would be best to put authors as “Sebastien Godard and others”.

Answer (score 3):

As [@Johannes_B](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/214677/citing-a-linux-manual-page-in-bibtex#comment503720_214677) said:

> manual seems to be ok

You already chose all the optional fields from the BibTeX-guide, which is great.

If it is in the manpage, the edition field might be abused to point to the edition of the software treated (this is uniquely identifying). For example

```
edition="4.3"
```

for the current bash manpage. This differs a bit from the manual, which states that

> **edition** The edition of a book—for example, “Second”. This
>                should be an ordinal, and should have the first letter
>                capitalized, as shown here; the standard styles convert
>                to lower case when necessary.

, but it also says

> feel free to be creative in how you use
>            these entry types